# Why my Cakephp web service query takes lot of time to return data?

Tags: php, arrays, api, cakephp

I've got a web service which takes around 15 secs to return JSON response to front-end.My code looks like this:

Controller code:

```
 public function getDetailReport($data){
 $user_id = $data->user_id;  
 $test_id = $data->test_id;  
   $result_obj = new TestSetDetailResultTable();
   $data_array = $result_obj->getDetailReportByUser($user_id, $test_id);
  if($data_array['status'] == 1) {

         echo  $this->successMessage('successfully Executed',$data_array['record']);
      } else {
         echo $this->failMessage($data_array['error'],$data_array['message']);
      }
 exit;
}
```

Model code:

```
public function getDetailReportByUser($user_id,$test_id) {
 $data_array = Array();
 $subject_array = Array();
 $answer_array = Array();
 $topper_array = Array();
 $percentile_array = Array();
 $max_marks = 0;
 $perc = 0;
 $hrs = 0;
 $mint = 0;
 $sec = 0;
  $query = new AppQuery();
  $query->callProcedure('getSummaryResult',array($test_id,$user_id));
  $row_list = $this->loadRowList($query); 

  if(count($row_list) > 0) {
      $max_marks = $row_list[0]->maximum_marks;
       $perc = $row_list[0]->percentage;
        $query->callProcedure('getCompletedTestTime',array($user_id,$test_id));
        $row_time = $this->loadRowList($query);  
         $query->callProcedure('getAllUserPerTest',array($test_id));
         $row_user = $this->loadRowList($query);
         if(count($row_time)> 0 && count($row_user) > 0) {
             foreach ($row_list as $list) {
                 $item['test_name'] = $list->test_name;
                 $item['total_question'] = $list->total_question;
                 $item['right_answer'] = $list->right_answer;
                 $item['wrong_answer'] = $list->wrong_answer;
                 $item['question_attempted'] = $list->question_attempted;
                 $item['question_not_attempted'] = $list->question_not_attempted;
                 $item['positive_marks'] = $list->positive_marks;
                 $item['negative_marks'] = $list->negative_marks;
                 $item['obtaine'] = $list->obtaine;
                  $item['maximum_test_time'] = $list->maximum_test_time;
                  $item['maximum_marks'] = $list->maximum_marks;
                  $item['test_date'] = $list->test_date;
                  $number = floatval($list->obtaine)* 100 / intval($list->maximum_marks);
                   $item['percentage'] = number_format($number, 2, '.', ''); // upto 2 decimal places
                  $data_array['detail'] = $item;
             }
                $tmp = Array();
                $hrs = $row_time[0]->spent_hours;
                $mint = $row_time[0]->spent_minute;
                $sec = $row_time[0]->spent_second;
                $completed_minute = $row_time[0]->compeleted_minute;
                 $completed_second = $row_time[0]->compeleted_second;
                 if($completed_second < 0) {
                  $completed_second = -1 * $completed_second; // only removing - sign   
                 }
                $tmp = $this->calculateTime($hrs, $mint, $sec);
                $tmp['compeleted_minute'] = $completed_minute;
                $tmp['compeleted_second'] = $completed_second;
             $data_array['time'] = $tmp;
             foreach ($row_user as $list) {
                 $tem['total_user'] = $list->total_user;
                  $data_array['users'] = $tem;
             }
             // Now get The subject wise Result
             $temp = Array();
             $query->callProcedure('getTestResult',array($test_id,$user_id));
            $subject_result = $this->loadRowList($query);
            foreach ($subject_result as $res) {
                 $temp['subject_name']= $res->subject_name;
                 $temp['marks_obtained'] = $res->obtaine;
                  $temp['total_question'] = $res->total_question;
                  $temp['question_attempted'] = $res->question_attempted;
                   $temp['wrong_answer'] = $res->wrong_answer;
                  // $temp['total_spent_hours'] = $res->total_spent_hours;
                  //  $temp['total_spent_minute'] = $res->total_spent_minute;
                   // $temp['total_spent_second'] = $res->total_spent_second;
                   $time_arr2 = $this->calculateTime($res->total_spent_hours, $res->total_spent_minute, $res->total_spent_second);
                   $temp['total_spent_hours'] = $time_arr2['hours'];
                   $temp['total_spent_minute'] = $time_arr2['minute'];;
                   $temp['total_spent_second'] = $time_arr2['second'];
                   $temp['max_marks'] = intval($res->total_question) * intval($res->positive_marks);
                      $subject_array[] = $temp;
            }
            $data_array['subject_result'] = $subject_array;

           //>>>>>>>>>>> Now get Answer of Question with Time spent>>>>>>>>>>
            $temp = Array();
             $query->callProcedure('getAnswerwithTime',array($test_id,$user_id));
            $answer_list = $this->loadRowList($query);
            foreach ($answer_list as $res) {
        $temp['question']= utf8_encode($res->question);
                 $temp['user_answer']= $res->user_answer;
                 $temp['correct_answer'] = $res->correct_answer;
                 $temp['spent_hours'] = $res->spent_hours;
                 $temp['spent_minute'] = $res->spent_minute;
                 $temp['spent_second'] = $res->spent_second;
                  $temp['obtaine'] = $res->obtaine;
                 $answer_array[] = $temp;    
            }
             $data_array['answer_with_time'] = $answer_array;

            /*>>>>>>>>End>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
             /*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>For Topper result for Comparing>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
             $temp = Array();
             $query->callProcedure('getTopperResult',array($test_id));
            $top_arr = $this->loadRowList($query);
            foreach ($top_arr as $top) {
              $temp['user_name'] =   $top->user_name;
              $temp['test_name'] =   $top->test_name;
              $temp['total_question'] =  $top->total_question;
              $temp['right_answer'] =   $top->right_answer;
              $temp['wrong_answer'] =   $top->wrong_answer;
              $temp['question_attempted'] =   $top->question_attempted;
              $temp['question_not_attempted'] =   $top->question_not_attempted;
              $temp['positive_marks'] =   $top->positive_marks;
              $temp['negative_marks'] =   $top->negative_marks;
              $temp['maximum_marks'] =   $top->maximum_marks;
              $temp['obtaine'] =   $top->obtaine;
              $temp['percentage'] =   $top->percentage;
              $temp['maximum_test_time'] =   $top->maximum_test_time;
              $temp['test_date'] =   $top->test_date;
               $timer = $this->calculateTime( $top->spent_hours, $top->spent_minute,  $top->spent_second);
              $temp['spent_hours'] = $timer['hours'];
              $temp['spent_minute'] = $timer['minute'];
              $temp['spent_second'] =  $timer['second'];
               $temp['completed_minute'] = $top->completed_minute;
               $sec_var = $top->completed_second;
               if($sec_var < 0) {
                  $sec_var = -1 * $sec_var; 
               }
              $temp['completed_second'] = $sec_var;
              $percentile = $this->getPercentileRank($test_id,$top->percentage,$top->maximum_marks);
               $temp['percentile'] = $percentile; // percentile
             //  $temp['rank'] = intval($percentile); // Rank
              $topper_array[] = $temp;
            }
            //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> topper array contain Topper Percentile,now we need to get Rank according to Percentile
            $topper_array = $this->rank($topper_array);
            $data_array['toppers_result'] = $topper_array;
              /*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>For Topper Result>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/

             /*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>For Login user Percentile>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
             $percentile = $this->getPercentileRank($test_id, $perc, $max_marks);
             $percentile_array = $this->loginUserRank($topper_array, $percentile);
             $data_array['percentile'] = $percentile_array;
              /*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>For Login user Percentile End>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
             /*>>>>>>>>>Get subject Wise Time of Toppers >>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
            $subject_wise_time =  $this->getSubjectWiseTopperTime($test_id);
            $data_array['subject_wise_topper_time'] = $subject_wise_time;
            /*>>>>>>>>>Get subject Wise Time of Toppers End >>>>>>>>>>>>>*/

             /*>>>>>>>>>Get Answer with Time of Toppers >>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
            $topper_answer_with_time = $this->topperAnswerTime($test_id);
            $data_array['topper_answer_with_time'] = $topper_answer_with_time;
             /*>>>>>>>>>Get Answer with Time of Toppers Ends >>>>>>>>>>>>>*/

            return $this->modelMessage(1,'non','success',$data_array); exit;
         } else {
            return $this->modelMessage($this->getStatus(),$this->getError(),$this->getMessage()); exit;

         }

  } else {
      return $this->modelMessage($this->getStatus(),$this->getError(),$this->getMessage()); exit;

  }
 }
```

I'm trying to debug this code but I don't know what am I missing here.How can this take 15 secs of time to return response back? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you debug than calculate the needed times with microtime(true), my guess are the DB querys for instance:

```
$start=microtime(true);
$answer_list = $this->loadRowList($query);
$stop=microtime(true);
$neededTime=$stop-$start;
echo "Time for answer_list $neededTime s for query $query";
```

Than you see what need to longest time. Than look on your query an look on your database schema. In most cases you can solve that issue by adding some indices on your db table. You can "debug" the query with explain on sql level, this will show you if you use an index.